# [[maybe_unused]] on enumerator

Tags: c++, attributes, language-lawyer, c++17

Looking at the specification of the [`[[maybe_unused]]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes), it states:

> Appears in the declaration of a class, a typedef­, a variable, a non­static data member, a function, an enumeration, or an enumerator. If the compiler issues warnings on unused entities, that warning is suppressed for any entity declared maybe_unused.

As this mentions enumerator, I kinda expect it to have a use-case. As the only thing I could come up with is the `-Wswitch` warning, I tried it with Clang, GCC and MSVC.

```
enum A
{
    B,
    C [[maybe_unused]]
};

void f(A a)
{
    switch (a)
    {
        case B: break;
    }
}
```

All 3 compilers give me a variation of following warning:

```
<source>:9:13: warning: enumeration value 'C' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
    switch (a)
            ^
```

[Live code](https://godbolt.org/g/kBGjiW)

Is this a valid use case for using this attribute, are there other use cases for adding the attribute at this location or is this just a useless addition?

Comment: Your quote says: "if the compiler issues warnings on unused entities, [...]" Well it didn't emit a warning for `A::C`, did it? But I guess I see what you mean.

Comment: Isn't `enumeration value 'C' not handled in switch` a warning on unused?

Comment: Good question. If `[[maybe_unused]]` on `C` doesn't mean "don't warn me about not using it," then I don't know what else it could mean.

Comment: Note that cppreference.com does not constitute specification. There is in fact *no* normative specification of this attribute, only suggestive notes that implementations may take any way they please.

Comment: @JVApen: I question wanting to do this. What is that enumerator doing such that not checking for its value in ***all*** `switch` statements is a reasonable thing? I can understand having specific switch statements where you don't check every value, but we have a way to spell that: stick `default:` at the end of the `switch` where you do that. Why would you need to specify that not checking for a particular enumerator is *always* OK?

Comment: Having a final value in your enum to do something more intelligent based on the number of values is a good example. Some bounds checking conventions, something to represent an invalid value. Basically, something that should be checked at the edges and never again afterward.

Comment: Although it's reasonable for clang to support your desired behavior, I don't think the Standard says anything about warnings on this code, since this is not the usual meaning of "used". I think it would apply to `namespace { enum { VALUE1, [[maybe_unused]] VALUE2 }; }` if `VALUE2` were not used in the rest of the TU, although the major compilers don't have any warnings on that without the attribute in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bug was logged for Clang and marked as resolved: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36231

This seems to confirm that the enum value is allowed to be missing in a switch without warning in case it is tagged with [[maybe_unused]]

Answer (score 6):

The intention of this attribute is to declare that an entity might never be made *use* of, and if that's the case, the implementation shouldn't bother warning you that somewhere, for example, you might be *using* a wrong entity.

`switch` statements are a completely different matter altogether: not *handling* an enumerator is problematic even if the enumerator is never *used* in that TU; it indicates a logical gap in your program. What if that function has external linkage, and someone else invokes it with that enumerator?

In short, even in TUs in which we marked an enumerator as potentially unused (which feels pointless, because at namespace scope they often are), covering it in your program logic is still very well-advised (and Clang is quite right in giving you that advice).

Comment: I read you answer, although, it does not look like it answers my question. (Maybe I'm reading wrong) Regardless of whether my code is good or not, I still don't know if the compiler is allowed to use this attribute for suppressing the warning.

Comment: @JVApen Define "allowed".

Comment: Given the description of the standard, is a suppression of this warning acceptable or not

Comment: @JVApen Anything is acceptable if we're talking about warnings. If that was your question, it was an idiotic one.

Comment: Actually, i'd love to add [[maybe_unused]] to enumator, only because I haven't implemented this one but have to import some corresponding code related to it.