# How do I mark one enum value as an inappropriate case in switches

Tags: c++, enums, compiler-warnings

Given an enum like:

```
enum Colours { RED, YELLOW, BLUE, NUM_COLOURS };
```

And some logic like:

```
switch (colour) {
case RED: /* ... */ break;
case YELLOW: /* ... */ break;
case BLUE: /* ... */ break;
}
```

Most compilers with reasonable settings are going to protest that `NUM_COLOURS` is an unhandled case.  However, that's obviously not how that particular value is meant to be used, and a case statement for it would be nonsense.

Is there any way to let the linter/compiler know that ignoring that specific value is correct and proper?  Or a way of determining that value without including it in the enum?

Comment: you have a default case that can do noting it should solve your issue https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

Comment: @alon except that's as good as compiling with `-Wall`, and you'll get no warning if you really forget a case - wouldn't recommend

Comment: how about using separate variable for your needs of NUM_COLOURS? like bool may work with a combination of the rest of enum

Comment: Personally I'll just compile with the warning off and add a `static_assert(NUM_COLOURS == 3)` to catch modifications.

Comment: Why can't you just do `case NUM_COLOURS: static_assert(NUM_COLOURS == 3); break;` ?

Comment: I recommend looking at one of my questions, indication that compilers don't support [[maybe_unused]], was recently fixed in Clang: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488635/maybe-unused-on-enumerator

Comment: `enum Colours { RED, YELLOW, BLUE }; enum { NUM_COLOURS = BLUE + 1 };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard complaint way of doing this is with `[[maybe_unused]]`. You can add it after the enumeration value:

```
enum A
{
    B,
   C [[maybe_unused]]
};

void f(A a)
{
    switch (a)
    {
        case B: break;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, compiler support for this ain't good. Clang recently resolved a bug to support this, must be in the upcoming 9.0.0 release (expected in September). (https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36231) GCC and MSVC didn't support it half a year ago, as I don't need those, never logged a bug on that.

If you want support in other compilers/linters, you'll most likely have to log a bug for that. Given the size of the patch in Clang, I don't expect it to bee too much effort to support this in other tools.

Answer (score 0):

@JVApen's answer is, I think, the ideal answer that I was looking for.  It's just a shame it doesn't sound like it's widely implemented.

In the interim, I realised that since I'm [already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57087772/2417578) using [X-Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x-macros) to build stringified names for my enums, I can use the same technique to count the number of values, so the count does not appear as a part of the enum type:

```
#define LIST_OF_COLOURS(X) \
    X(RED) \
    X(GREEN) \
    X(BLUE)

#define LIST_OF_FRUIT(X) \
    X(APPLE) \
    X(ORANGE) \
    X(TOMATO)

#define X_LIST(x) x,
#define X_STRING_LIST(x) #x,
#define X_COUNT(x) +1
#define COMPREHENSIVE_SETUP(n, l)  \
    enum n { l(X_LIST) };  \
    char const* n##Names[] = { l(X_STRING_LIST) };  \
    enum { n##Count = 0 l(X_COUNT) };

COMPREHENSIVE_SETUP(Colour, LIST_OF_COLOURS)
COMPREHENSIVE_SETUP(Fruit, LIST_OF_FRUIT)
```

The trick being the last line of the `COMPREHENSIVE_SETUP` macro.

With that I can have `ColourCount` and `FruitCount` constants in place of `NUM_COLOURS`, and they're not a part of the enum so they don't need to appear in the switch.